# java servlet get cookie value in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, cookies

In java servlet I have following code:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {       
    Cookie cookie = new Cookie("tom_cookies",Long.toString(new Date().getTime()));
    cookie.setMaxAge(30);
    cookie.setPath(request.getContextPath());
    cookie.setComment("1");
    cookie.setVersion(1);
    System.out.println("Cookie created!");
    response.addCookie(cookie);
}
```

In JSP index.jsp I have following code:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>MyIndex</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>CookieComment: <%
Cookie[] my = request.getCookies();
for(int i=0;i<my.length;i++){
String comment = my[i].getComment();
out.println(comment);
}
%> 
</div></body></html>
```

My web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<servlet>
<servlet-name>Test</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>Servlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>Test</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/servlet1</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<display-name>1aaa</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

In local:8080/servlet, what I expect is like:

> CookieComment: 1

However, it only shows:

> CookieComment: null

whats wrong here?

Comment: cookies expire in 30 seconds ? do you use it before expire ?

Comment: Yes, I use it before 30 sec. To be sure, I changed MaxAge to 30*60. Still shows 'null'

Comment: For my sanity sake, and for a test, what do you get when you adjust line 10 in index.html/jsp to `String comment = my[i].getName();`? (You should get `tom_cookies` if your servlet has run before your index runs)

Comment: It is ''JSESSIONID'', which I don't even know what that is.

Comment: Ok, this means your java servlet isn't actually executing when you load index.jsp, remember, they are two different "pages" if I can call it that. What is in your web.xml file? This is where you define your servlet. If it's empty, I will post an answer to help you create one.

Comment: I uploaded my web.xml above, pls take a look at it.

Comment: Looks good, ok now try this, run `local:8080/servlet1` (don't forget the 1 part) and immediately after that run your original page and tell me what you get? (granted that your line 10 still uses `getName()`.

Comment: nothing changed, it looks the same. i put 1 after it

Comment: @TomDawn - apologies, I've just seen my error. It should be `local:8080/servlet/servlet1` (I've edited the comment below now)

Comment: So let me clarify. You ran `local:8080/servlet/servlet1` (a blank page should show), then you ran `local:8080/servlet` and it still shows CookieComment: null? Is line 10 set to `String comment = my[i].getName();` for this test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not really need to get the cookies from the request object via scriptlet code, you can use the implicit variable called 'cookie' via EL

```
${cookie.yourCookieName}
```

This should print the value of your cookie in the JSP page. It looks for the cookie in the response object

Hope it helps

Comment: Thx Alberto, I tried your method and found that it actually worked in Java EE internal browser! However it doesn't show in Chrome. I am wondering why that happen?

Comment: Well, you could have the chrome cookies disabled, enter setting and search for cookies support, if that doesnt help, you could try using some rewriting url, from the EE api's. But mostly, is because chrome does not support cookies

Answer (score 1):

This is how cookies work:

1. Browser sends a request to server.
2. Server script sends a set of cookies to the browser.
3. Browser stores this information on local machine for future use.
4. When next time browser sends any request to web server then it sends those cookies information to the server and server uses that information to identify the user.

What you are trying to do is, access the cookies set in response object (step 2) from request object(step 1). As request object clearly has no idea of the cookie set in response, you are getting `null` value.

You can only access cookie in the **subsequent** request sent by browser (please note that although the code between `<%` and `%>` is written in html/jsp, it is actually server side code and is executed before response is rendered.

If you want to pass something back from server and print it then you can use `response` object or [set attributes](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2063481?start=0&tstart=0) in `request`.

Comment: thx for the explanation, I think I get what you are saying. However, the **response** object does not have getCookie() method, how can I get cookie value in this case?

Comment: You need to send another request from browser once the whole page is rendered. That request should include cookie. Btw, why do you want to have cookies? You can simply use `session.getAttribute()` and `session.setAttribute()` methods to share data between different requests and responses belonging to one session.

Comment: I need cookie for later use. This is going to be a large project starting from small part.